# How to use Nginx as a reverse proxy for connecting to AWS S3?

Tags: nginx, ssl, curl, tls1.2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to set up a reverse proxy to redirect my internal users making requests to myserver:443/mybucket to https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/mybucket. The Nginx server is on Amazon Linux 2023. I have also 2 others buckets for which I need a redirection.

I have configured the below nginx.conf file :

```
server {
 server_name myserver;
 listen      443;
 rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/$1 permanent;
 location / {
 allow 10.0.0.0/8;
 deny all;
 }
 }
```

When I want to test if the redirection works using curl, I have below errors :

```
# curl -k -I https://myserver/mybucket
curl: (35) OpenSSL/3.0.8: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
```

If I use http instead of https :

```
# curl -I http://myserver/mybucket
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.24.0
Date: Wed, 16 Aug 2023 15:01:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket
```

I am thinking that I may need to create an SSL Certificate for my server that my users will use.
For testing purposes, I have created a self-signed certificate on my Nginx server and added it to the configuration :

```
server {
 server_name myserver;
 ssl_certificate /usr/cert/certificate.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /usr/cert/private.key;
 listen      443;
 rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/$1 permanent;
 location / {
 allow 10.0.0.0/8;
 deny all;
 }
 }
```

I then tested again and added -vv for getting more details but same error :

```
# curl -vv -k -I https://myserver/mybucket
*   Trying myserver...
* Connected to myserver port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL/3.0.8: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL/3.0.8: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
```

Is there anything I have missed in the set up ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

I just needed to enable ssl and modify the line below in my nginx.conf file :

```
listen      443;
```

to

```
listen      443 ssl;
```